# C# Warning: Cannot find lib.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build the solution, but the warning message appeared, where can I find this lib.exe?

Comment: can you include more information about your project?

Comment: build a dll, for encog framework (neural network)

Comment: Old question, but I fixed this error by updating a `.targets` file that was associated with my project. It had a list of target directories for dependency files that I was able to change. Ended up asking a new question on stack to figure it out.